# Forcing a DNS failure

Tags: testing, dns

I need to test a change in our application's DNS retry behavior.

It previously switched into another mode to report the issue to the end user, but we've found a bug when the retry attempt worked, it would proceed to try loading the now-found far-end service in that "error reporting" mode.

To fix this, we have disabled the switch to the error reporting mode, and expect that on a successful retry we will load into the expected mode.

*Thus, I need DNS (rndc/named) to fail once, and only once, and provide a successful result on the second attempt.*

The only thing I can think is to run a large load test, and hope DNS fails like this at some point... But I am hoping someone on here might know of a better solution.

Maybe a way to block the connection attempt once ? The DNS server is part of the application, though, so it would be blocking the connection to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

for sure you can use docker/vm/dedicated os, change its dns settings and use it as a dns resolver. it will be probably a lot of work to script it but it seems possible. but before it i would look for some dns mock service/server